# How to make "keyword-only" fields with dataclasses?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

[Since 3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) there is support to make an argument keyword only:

```
class S3Obj:
    def __init__(self, bucket, key, *, storage_class='Standard'):
        self.bucket = bucket
        self.key = key
        self.storage_class = storage_class
```

How to get that kind of signature using [dataclasses](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/)?  Something like this, but preferably without the `SyntaxError`:

```
@dataclass
class S3Obj:
    bucket: str
    key: str
    *
    storage_class: str = 'Standard'
```

Ideally declarative, but using the `__post_init__` hook and/or a replacement class decorator is fine too - as long as the code is reusable.

*Edit:* maybe something like this syntax, using an ellipsis literal

```
@mydataclass
class S3Obj:
    bucket: str
    key: str
    ...
    storage_class: str = 'Standard'
```

Comment: `...` won't do anything any other code could see.

Comment: This has been somewhat silently been added to 3.10: https://bugs.python.org/issue33129

Comment: If you're using < Python 3.10, my answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095470/5087436) provides a way to declare fields without defaults after fields with defaults. This is not equivalent to keyword-only, but does solve some of the same problems keyword-only solves as well (e.g. defaults on a base dataclass that is inherited).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Python 3.10+, there's a [`dataclasses.KW_ONLY`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.KW_ONLY) sentinel that works like this:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Example:
    a: int
    b: int
    _: dataclasses.KW_ONLY
    c: int
    d: int
```

Any fields after the `KW_ONLY` pseudo-field are keyword-only.

There's also a `kw_only` parameter to the `dataclasses.dataclass` decorator, which makes all fields keyword-only:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Example:
    a: int
    b: int
```

It's also possible to pass `kw_only=True` to `dataclasses.field` to mark individual fields as keyword-only.

If keyword-only fields come after non-keyword-only fields (possible with inheritance, or by individually marking fields keyword-only), keyword-only fields will be [reordered](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dataclasses.html#re-ordering-of-keyword-only-parameters-in-init) after other fields, specifically for the purpose of `__init__`. Other dataclass functionality will keep the declared order. This reordering is confusing and should probably be avoided.

---

Pre-Python 3.10 answer:

You're not going to get much help from `dataclasses` when doing this. There's no way to say that a field should be initialized by keyword-only argument, and the `__post_init__` hook doesn't know whether the original constructor arguments were passed by keyword. Also, there's no good way to introspect `InitVar`s, let alone mark `InitVar`s as keyword-only.

At minimum, you'll have to replace the generated `__init__`. Probably the simplest way is to just define `__init__` by hand. If you don't want to do that, probably the most robust way is to create field objects and mark them kwonly in the `metadata`, then inspect the metadata in your own decorator. This is even more complicated than it sounds:

```
import dataclasses
import functools
import inspect

# Helper to make calling field() less verbose
def kwonly(default=dataclasses.MISSING, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('metadata', {})
    kwargs['metadata']['kwonly'] = True
    return dataclasses.field(default=default, **kwargs)

def mydataclass(_cls, *, init=True, **kwargs):
    if _cls is None:
        return functools.partial(mydataclass, **kwargs)

    no_generated_init = (not init or '__init__' in _cls.__dict__)
    _cls = dataclasses.dataclass(_cls, **kwargs)
    if no_generated_init:
        # No generated __init__. The user will have to provide __init__,
        # and they probably already have. We assume their __init__ does
        # what they want.
        return _cls

    fields = dataclasses.fields(_cls)
    if any(field.metadata.get('kwonly') and not field.init for field in fields):
        raise TypeError('Non-init field marked kwonly')

    # From this point on, ignore non-init fields - but we don't know
    # about InitVars yet.
    init_fields = [field for field in fields if field.init]
    for i, field in enumerate(init_fields):
        if field.metadata.get('kwonly'):
            first_kwonly = field.name
            num_kwonly = len(init_fields) - i
            break
    else:
        # No kwonly fields. Why were we called? Assume there was a reason.
        return _cls

    if not all(field.metadata.get('kwonly') for field in init_fields[-num_kwonly:]):
        raise TypeError('non-kwonly init fields following kwonly fields')

    required_kwonly = [field.name for field in init_fields[-num_kwonly:]
                       if field.default is field.default_factory is dataclasses.MISSING]

    original_init = _cls.__init__

    # Time to handle InitVars. This is going to get ugly.
    # InitVars don't show up in fields(). They show up in __annotations__,
    # but the current dataclasses implementation doesn't understand string
    # annotations, and we want an implementation that's robust against
    # changes in string annotation handling.
    # We could inspect __post_init__, except there doesn't have to be a
    # __post_init__. (It'd be weird to use InitVars with no __post_init__,
    # but it's allowed.)
    # As far as I can tell, that leaves inspecting __init__ parameters as
    # the only option.

    init_params = tuple(inspect.signature(original_init).parameters)
    if init_params[-num_kwonly] != first_kwonly:
        # InitVars following kwonly fields. We could adopt a convention like
        # "InitVars after kwonly are kwonly" - in fact, we could have adopted
        # "all fields after kwonly are kwonly" too - but it seems too likely
        # to cause confusion with inheritance.
        raise TypeError('InitVars after kwonly fields.')
    # -1 to exclude self from this count.
    max_positional = len(init_params) - num_kwonly - 1

    @functools.wraps(original_init)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > max_positional:
            raise TypeError('Too many positional arguments')
        check_required_kwargs(kwargs, required_kwonly)
        return original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
    _cls.__init__ = __init__

    return _cls

def check_required_kwargs(kwargs, required):
    # Not strictly necessary, but if we don't do this, error messages for
    # required kwonly args will list them as positional instead of
    # keyword-only.
    missing = [name for name in required if name not in kwargs]
    if not missing:
        return
    # We don't bother to exactly match the built-in logic's exception
    raise TypeError(f"__init__ missing required keyword-only argument(s): {missing}")
```

Usage example:

```
@mydataclass
class S3Obj:
    bucket: str
    key: str
    storage_class: str = kwonly('Standard')
```

This is somewhat tested, but not as thoroughly as I would like.

---

You can't get the syntax you propose with `...`, because `...` doesn't do anything a metaclass or decorator can see. You can get something pretty close with something that actually triggers name lookup or assignment, like `kwonly_start = True`, so a metaclass can see it happen. However, a robust implementation of this is complicated to write, because there are a lot of things that need dedicated handling. Inheritance, `typing.ClassVar`, `dataclasses.InitVar`, forward references in annotations, etc. will all cause problems if not handled carefully. Inheritance probably causes the most problems.

A proof-of-concept that doesn't handle all the fiddly bits might look like this:

```
# Does not handle inheritance, InitVar, ClassVar, or anything else
# I'm forgetting.

class POCMetaDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        # __setitem__ instead of __getitem__ because __getitem__ is
        # easier to trigger by accident.
        if key == 'kwonly_start':
            self['__non_kwonly'] = len(self['__annotations__'])
        super().__setitem__(key, item)

class POCMeta(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(cls, name, bases, **kwargs):
        return POCMetaDict()
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict, **kwargs):
        classdict.pop('kwonly_start')
        non_kwonly = classdict.pop('__non_kwonly')

        newcls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, classdict, **kwargs)
        newcls = dataclass(newcls)

        if non_kwonly is None:
            return newcls

        original_init = newcls.__init__

        @functools.wraps(original_init)
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if len(args) > non_kwonly:
                raise TypeError('Too many positional arguments')
            return original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

        newcls.__init__ = __init__
        return newcls
```

You'd use it like

```
class S3Obj(metaclass=POCMeta):
    bucket: str
    key: str

    kwonly_start = True

    storage_class: str = 'Standard'
```

This is untested.

Comment: Update for https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/25608 ?

Comment: @wim: Updated for upcoming 3.10 functionality.

Comment: The pre-3.10 solution seems way more complicated than it needs to be? Seems to me that once you've created `MyDataClass`, you can just do `original_init = MyDataClass.__init__`, then define `def new_init(self, ..., *, kw_only_arg, ...): original_init(self, ..., kw_only_arg=kw_only_arg, ...)`, and then finally `MyDataClass.__init__ = new_init`... I don't have time to test right now but I think that should be good enough?

Comment: @mtraceur: You'd have to hardcode the names of the keyword-only arguments for that to work.

Comment: Yes, obviously (unless you're making all arguments keyword-only, in which case you could just use `**kwargs` in the wrapper init), but I think the simplicity and brevity of that is better for one-off or a-few-dataclasses-in-the-project situations than all of the above. But I do agree that there is an inflection point where eventually the implementation in this question is better than repeating the boilerplate of simpler solutions.

Answer (score 9):

I wonder why this is not part of the dataclass API, that seems important to me.

If all arguments are keyword arguments maybe its a bit simpler and the following could suffice?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import wraps

def kwargs_only(cls):
    
    @wraps(cls)
    def call(**kwargs):
        return cls(**kwargs)
    
    return call

@kwargs_only
@dataclass
class Coordinates:
    latitude: float = 0
    longitude: float = 0
```

That's not perfect because the error when using positional argument refers to `call`:

```sh
--------------------------------------------------------
TypeError              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-fb588c816ecf> in <module>
----> 1 c = Coordinates(1, longitude=2)
      2 help(c)

TypeError: call() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Similarly the dataclass' constructor documentation is outdated and doesn't reflect the new constraint.

If there are only some keyword fields, maybe this?

```py
def kwargs(*keywords):
    
    def decorator(cls):
        @wraps(cls)
        def call(*args, **kwargs):
            if any(kw not in kwargs for kw in keywords):
                raise TypeError(f"{cls.__name__}.__init__() requires {keywords} as keyword arguments")
            return cls(*args, **kwargs)
        
        return call

    return decorator


@kwargs('longitude')
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Coordinates:
    latitude: float
    longitude: float = 0
```