# Class inheritance in Python 3.7 dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I'm currently trying my hands on the new dataclass constructions introduced in Python 3.7. I am currently stuck on trying to do some inheritance of a parent class. It looks like the order of the arguments are botched by my current approach such that the bool parameter in the child class is passed before the other parameters. This is causing a type error.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Parent:
    name: str
    age: int
    ugly: bool = False

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def print_age(self):
        print(self.age)

    def print_id(self):
        print(f'The Name is {self.name} and {self.name} is {self.age} year old')

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    school: str
    ugly: bool = True


jack = Parent('jack snr', 32, ugly=True)
jack_son = Child('jack jnr', 12, school = 'havard', ugly=True)

jack.print_id()
jack_son.print_id()
```

When I run this code I get this `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: non-default argument 'school' follows default argument
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that within the attrs / dataclass typed python paradigm, composition is usually preferred over inheritance. Extending your subclass's `__init__` like this is vaguely a violation of [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), because your various subclasses won't be interchangeable. To be clear, I think this way is often practical, but in case you haven't considered using composition: it might also make sense to make a `Child` dataclass that doesn't inherit, and then have a `child` attribute on the `Parent` class.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

The way dataclasses combines attributes prevents you from being able to use attributes with defaults in a base class and then use attributes without a default (positional attributes) in a subclass.

That's because the attributes are combined by starting from the bottom of the MRO, and building up an ordered list of the attributes in first-seen order; overrides are kept in their original location. So `Parent` starts out with `['name', 'age', 'ugly']`, where `ugly` has a default, and then `Child` adds `['school']` to the end of that list (with `ugly` already in the list). This means you end up with `['name', 'age', 'ugly', 'school']` and because `school` doesn't have a default, this results in an invalid argument listing for `__init__`.

This is documented in [PEP-557 *Dataclasses*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/), under [*inheritance*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#inheritance):

> When the Data Class is being created by the `@dataclass` decorator, it looks through all of the class's base classes in reverse MRO (that is, starting at `object`) and, for each Data Class that it finds, adds the fields from that base class to an ordered mapping of fields. After all of the base class fields are added, it adds its own fields to the ordered mapping. All of the generated methods will use this combined, calculated ordered mapping of fields. Because the fields are in insertion order, derived classes override base classes.

and under [*Specification*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#id7):

> `TypeError` will be raised if a field without a default value follows a field with a default value. This is true either when this occurs in a single class, or as a result of class inheritance.

You do have a few options here to avoid this issue.

The first option is to use separate base classes to force fields with defaults into a later position in the MRO order. At all cost, avoid setting fields directly on classes that are to be used as base classes, such as `Parent`.

The following class hierarchy works:

```
# base classes with fields; fields without defaults separate from fields with.
@dataclass
class _ParentBase:
    name: str
    age: int
    
@dataclass
class _ParentDefaultsBase:
    ugly: bool = False

@dataclass
class _ChildBase(_ParentBase):
    school: str

@dataclass
class _ChildDefaultsBase(_ParentDefaultsBase):
    ugly: bool = True

# public classes, deriving from base-with, base-without field classes
# subclasses of public classes should put the public base class up front.

@dataclass
class Parent(_ParentDefaultsBase, _ParentBase):
    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def print_age(self):
        print(self.age)

    def print_id(self):
        print(f"The Name is {self.name} and {self.name} is {self.age} year old")

@dataclass
class Child(_ChildDefaultsBase, Parent, _ChildBase):
    pass
```

By pulling out fields into *separate* base classes with fields without defaults and fields with defaults, and a carefully selected inheritance order, you can produce an MRO that puts all fields without defaults before those with defaults. The reversed MRO (ignoring `object`) for `Child` is:

```
_ParentBase
_ChildBase
_ParentDefaultsBase
Parent
_ChildDefaultsBase
```

Note that while `Parent` doesn't set any new fields, it does inherit the fields from `_ParentDefaultsBase` and should *not* end up 'last' in the field listing order; the above order puts `_ChildDefaultsBase` last so its fields 'win'. The dataclass rules are also satisfied; the classes with fields without defaults (`_ParentBase` and `_ChildBase`) precede the classes with fields with defaults (`_ParentDefaultsBase` and `_ChildDefaultsBase`).

The result is `Parent` and `Child` classes with a sane field older, while `Child` is still a subclass of `Parent`:

```
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> signature(Parent)
<Signature (name: str, age: int, ugly: bool = False) -> None>
>>> signature(Child)
<Signature (name: str, age: int, school: str, ugly: bool = True) -> None>
>>> issubclass(Child, Parent)
True
```

and so you can create instances of both classes:

```
>>> jack = Parent('jack snr', 32, ugly=True)
>>> jack_son = Child('jack jnr', 12, school='havard', ugly=True)
>>> jack
Parent(name='jack snr', age=32, ugly=True)
>>> jack_son
Child(name='jack jnr', age=12, school='havard', ugly=True)
```

Another option is to only use fields with defaults; you can still make in an error to not supply a `school` value, by raising one in `__post_init__`:

```
_no_default = object()

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    school: str = _no_default
    ugly: bool = True

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.school is _no_default:
            raise TypeError("__init__ missing 1 required argument: 'school'")
```

but this *does* alter the field order; `school` ends up after `ugly`:

```
<Signature (name: str, age: int, ugly: bool = True, school: str = <object object at 0x1101d1210>) -> None>
```

and a type hint checker *will* complain about `_no_default` not being a string.

You can also use the [`attrs` project](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/), which was the project that inspired `dataclasses`. It uses a different inheritance merging strategy; it pulls overridden fields in a subclass to the end of the fields list, so `['name', 'age', 'ugly']` in the `Parent` class becomes `['name', 'age', 'school', 'ugly']` in the `Child` class; by overriding the field with a default, `attrs` allows the override without needing to do a MRO dance.

`attrs` supports defining fields without type hints, but lets stick to the [supported type hinting mode](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/types.html) by setting `auto_attribs=True`:

```
import attr

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class Parent:
    name: str
    age: int
    ugly: bool = False

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def print_age(self):
        print(self.age)

    def print_id(self):
        print(f"The Name is {self.name} and {self.name} is {self.age} year old")

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class Child(Parent):
    school: str
    ugly: bool = True
```

Answer (score 125):

Note that with **Python 3.10**, it is now possible to do it natively with dataclasses.

Dataclasses 3.10 added the `kw_only` attribute (similar to [attrs](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/)).
It allows you to specify which fields are keyword_only, thus will be set at the end of the **init**, not causing an inheritance problem.

Taking directly from [Eric Smith's blog post on the subject](https://www.trueblade.com/blogs/news/python-3-10-new-dataclass-features):

> There are two reasons people [were asking for] this feature:
>
> - When a dataclass has many fields, specifying them by position can become unreadable. It also requires that for backward compatibility, all new fields are added to the end of the dataclass. This isn't always desirable.
> - **When a dataclass inherits from another dataclass, and the base class has fields with default values, then all of the fields in the derived class must also have defaults.**

What follows is the simplest way to do it with this new argument, but there are multiple ways you can use it to use inheritance with default values in the parent class:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Parent:
    name: str
    age: int
    ugly: bool = False

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Child(Parent):
    school: str

ch = Child(name="Kevin", age=17, school="42")
print(ch.ugly)
```

Take a look at the blogpost linked above for a more thorough explanation of kw_only.

Cheers !

*PS: As it is fairly new, note that your IDE might still raise a possible error, but it works at runtime*

Comment: Note that you can also use `kw_only=True` on a specific field. In the above example you could write `ugly: bool = field(default=False, kw_only=True)` and this would make only the `ugly` field keyword-only, leaving the other fields as required fields.

Comment: I had to pass `kw_only=True` argument only to the child class and not to the parent class to get this working. @ross's suggestion to use `ugly: bool = field(default=False, kw_only=True` didn't work for me. I am using `python 3.10.2`.

Answer (score 98):

You can use attributes with defaults in parent classes if you exclude them from the init function. If you need the possibility to override the default at init, extend the code with the answer of Praveen Kulkarni.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Parent:
    name: str
    age: int
    ugly: bool = field(default=False, init=False)

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    school: str

jack = Parent('jack snr', 32)
jack_son = Child('jack jnr', 12, school = 'havard')
jack_son.ugly = True
```

Or even

```
@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    school: str
    ugly = True
    # This does not work
    # ugly: bool = True

jack_son = Child('jack jnr', 12, school = 'havard')
assert jack_son.ugly
```

Comment: I think this answer should be more recognised. It's solved the problem of having a default field in the parent class, thus removes the TypeError.

Comment: You could add a `__post_init__` with the default value: `def __post_init__(self): self.ugly = True`

Comment: The drawback here is that we can't specify ugly in the Child constructor. 

```
>>> jack_son = Child('jack jnr', 12, school = 'havard', ugly=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ugly'
```

Answer (score 14):

The approach below deals with this problem while using pure python `dataclasses` and without much boilerplate code.

The `ugly: dataclasses.InitVar[bool]` serves as a [pseudo-field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables) just to help us do initialization and will be lost once the instance is created. While `_ugly: bool = field(init=False)` is an instance member which will not be initialized by `__init__` method but can be alternatively initialized using `__post_init__` method (you can find more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables).).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar

@dataclass
class Parent:
    name: str
    age: int
    ugly: InitVar[bool]
    _ugly: bool = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self, ugly: bool):
        self._ugly = ugly

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def print_age(self):
        print(self.age)

    def print_id(self):
        print(f'The Name is {self.name} and {self.name} is {self.age} year old')

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    school: str

jack = Parent('jack snr', 32, ugly=True)
jack_son = Child('jack jnr', 12, school='havard', ugly=True)

jack.print_id()
jack_son.print_id()
```

Note that this makes field `ugly` mandatory to make it optional you can define a class method on the Parent that includes `ugly` as an optional parameter:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, InitVar

@dataclass
class Parent:
    name: str
    age: int
    ugly: InitVar[bool]
    _ugly: bool = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self, ugly: bool):
        self._ugly = ugly
    
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, ugly=True, **kwargs):
        return cls(ugly=ugly, **kwargs)

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def print_age(self):
        print(self.age)

    def print_id(self):
        print(f'The Name is {self.name} and {self.name} is {self.age} year old')

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    school: str

jack = Parent.create(name='jack snr', age=32, ugly=False)
jack_son = Child.create(name='jack jnr', age=12, school='harvard')

jack.print_id()
jack_son.print_id()
```

Now you can use the `create(...)` class method as a factory method for creating Parent/Child classes with a default value for `ugly`.  Note you must use named parameters for this approach to work.

Comment: ugly_init now is a required parameter with no default

Comment: Yes and that is why you need to use factory method `create()` :( ...
Unless dataclassses allow InitiVar fields to have default value ;)

Comment: If you're using a factory method, then there isn't any need to do any of the pseudo-param, \_\_post_init__ stuff, you can just specify the default in the factory method signature. This isn't really ideal for classes with a lot of fields, because then you have to choose between either duplicating the field names and their type annotations in the factory method signature, or losing the type checking for the factory method by using **kwargs instead.

Answer (score 11):

You're seeing this error because an argument without a default value is being added after an argument with a default value.  The insertion order of inherited fields into the dataclass is the reverse of [Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), which means that the `Parent` fields come first, even if they are over written later by their children.

An example from [PEP-557 - Data Classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#inheritance):

> ```
> @dataclass
> class Base:
>     x: Any = 15.0
>     y: int = 0
>
> @dataclass
> class C(Base):
>     z: int = 10
>     x: int = 15
> ```
>
> The final list of fields is, in order,`x, y, z`. The final type of `x` is `int`, as specified in class `C`.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way around this. My understanding is that if the parent class has a default argument, then no child class can have non-default arguments.

Comment: I get that the non default argument must come before the default one but how can it when the parent arguments initialise before adding the child arguments?

Comment: I don't think there's any way around it unfortunately.  My understanding is that if the parent class has a default argument, then no child class can have non-default arguments.

Comment: Can you add that info to the answer before I mark it? It will help someone one day. It's quite unfortunate that limitation of dataclasses. Renders it moot my current python project. It's nice to see such implementations tho

Answer (score 7):

based on Martijn Pieters solution I did the following:

1) Create a mixing implementing the post_init

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

no_default = object()


@dataclass
class NoDefaultAttributesPostInitMixin:

    def __post_init__(self):
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            if value is no_default:
                raise TypeError(
                    f"__init__ missing 1 required argument: '{key}'"
                )
```

2) Then in the classes with the inheritance problem:

```
from src.utils import no_default, NoDefaultAttributesChild

@dataclass
class MyDataclass(DataclassWithDefaults, NoDefaultAttributesPostInitMixin):
    attr1: str = no_default
```

EDIT:

After a time I also find problems with this solution with mypy, the following code fix the issue.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Union

T = TypeVar("T")


class NoDefault(Generic[T]):
    ...


NoDefaultVar = Union[NoDefault[T], T]
no_default: NoDefault = NoDefault()


@dataclass
class NoDefaultAttributesPostInitMixin:
    def __post_init__(self):
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            if value is NoDefault:
                raise TypeError(f"__init__ missing 1 required argument: '{key}'")


@dataclass
class Parent(NoDefaultAttributesPostInitMixin):
    a: str = ""

@dataclass
class Child(Foo):
    b: NoDefaultVar[str] = no_default
```

Comment: Did you intend to write "class MyDataclass(DataclassWithDefaults, NoDefaultAttributesPostInitMixin)" above in 2)?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python 3.10+, then you can utilize keyword-only arguments for the dataclass as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911616/5087436) and in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.KW_ONLY).

If you're using < Python 3.10, then you can utilize `dataclasses.field` with a `default_factory` that throws. Since the attribute will be declared with `field()`, it gets treated as if it has a default; but if a user attempts to create an instance without providing the value for that field, it will use the factory, which will error.

This technique isn't equivalent to *keyword only*, because you could still provide all the arguments positionally. However, this does solve the problem, and is simpler than messing around with various dataclass dunder methods.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


def required() -> T:
    f: T

    def factory() -> T:
        # mypy treats a Field as a T, even though it has attributes like .name, .default, etc
        field_name = f.name  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
        raise ValueError(f"field '{field_name}' required")

    f = field(default_factory=factory)
    return f


@dataclass
class Event:
    id: str
    created_at: datetime
    updated_at: Optional[datetime] = None


@dataclass
class NamedEvent(Event):
    name: str = required()


event = NamedEvent(name="Some Event", id="ab13c1a", created_at=datetime.now())
print("created event:", event)


event2 = NamedEvent("ab13c1a", datetime.now(), name="Some Other Event")
print("created event:", event2)

event3 = NamedEvent("ab13c1a", datetime.now())
```

Output:

```
created event: NamedEvent(id='ab13c1a', created_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 23, 19, 22, 17, 944550), updated_at=None, name='Some Event')
created event: NamedEvent(id='ab13c1a', created_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 23, 19, 22, 17, 944588), updated_at=None, name='Some Other Event')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../gist.py", line 39, in <module>
    event3 = NamedEvent("ab13c1a", datetime.now())
  File "<string>", line 6, in __init__
  File ".../gist.py", line 14, in factory
    raise ValueError(f"field '{field_name}' required")
ValueError: field 'name' required
```

You can also find this code on [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/alkasm/80a13a62615e0889b60d5f0156625d5b).

Answer (score 2):

A possible work-around is to use monkey-patching to *append* the parent fields

```
import dataclasses as dc

def add_args(parent): 
    def decorator(orig):
        "Append parent's fields AFTER orig's fields"

        # Aggregate fields
        ff  = [(f.name, f.type, f) for f in dc.fields(dc.dataclass(orig))]
        ff += [(f.name, f.type, f) for f in dc.fields(dc.dataclass(parent))]

        new = dc.make_dataclass(orig.__name__, ff)
        new.__doc__ = orig.__doc__

        return new
    return decorator

class Animal:
    age: int = 0 

@add_args(Animal)
class Dog:
    name: str
    noise: str = "Woof!"

@add_args(Animal)
class Bird:
    name: str
    can_fly: bool = True

Dog("Dusty", 2)               # --> Dog(name='Dusty', noise=2, age=0)
b = Bird("Donald", False, 40) # --> Bird(name='Donald', can_fly=False, age=40)
```

It's also possible to *prepend* non-default fields,
by checking `if f.default is dc.MISSING`,
but this is probably too dirty.

While monkey-patching lacks some features of inheritance,
it can still be used to add methods to all pseudo-child classes.

For more fine-grained control, set the default values 
using `dc.field(compare=False, repr=True, ...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a modified version of dataclasses, which will generate a keyword only `__init__` method:

```py
import dataclasses


def _init_fn(fields, frozen, has_post_init, self_name):
    # fields contains both real fields and InitVar pseudo-fields.
    globals = {'MISSING': dataclasses.MISSING,
               '_HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORY': dataclasses._HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORY}

    body_lines = []
    for f in fields:
        line = dataclasses._field_init(f, frozen, globals, self_name)
        # line is None means that this field doesn't require
        # initialization (it's a pseudo-field).  Just skip it.
        if line:
            body_lines.append(line)

    # Does this class have a post-init function?
    if has_post_init:
        params_str = ','.join(f.name for f in fields
                              if f._field_type is dataclasses._FIELD_INITVAR)
        body_lines.append(f'{self_name}.{dataclasses._POST_INIT_NAME}({params_str})')

    # If no body lines, use 'pass'.
    if not body_lines:
        body_lines = ['pass']

    locals = {f'_type_{f.name}': f.type for f in fields}
    return dataclasses._create_fn('__init__',
                      [self_name, '*'] + [dataclasses._init_param(f) for f in fields if f.init],
                      body_lines,
                      locals=locals,
                      globals=globals,
                      return_type=None)


def add_init(cls, frozen):
    fields = getattr(cls, dataclasses._FIELDS)

    # Does this class have a post-init function?
    has_post_init = hasattr(cls, dataclasses._POST_INIT_NAME)

    # Include InitVars and regular fields (so, not ClassVars).
    flds = [f for f in fields.values()
            if f._field_type in (dataclasses._FIELD, dataclasses._FIELD_INITVAR)]
    dataclasses._set_new_attribute(cls, '__init__',
                       _init_fn(flds,
                                frozen,
                                has_post_init,
                                # The name to use for the "self"
                                # param in __init__.  Use "self"
                                # if possible.
                                '__dataclass_self__' if 'self' in fields
                                else 'self',
                                ))

    return cls


# a dataclass with a constructor that only takes keyword arguments
def dataclass_keyword_only(_cls=None, *, repr=True, eq=True, order=False,
              unsafe_hash=False, frozen=False):
    def wrap(cls):
        cls = dataclasses.dataclass(
            cls, init=False, repr=repr, eq=eq, order=order, unsafe_hash=unsafe_hash, frozen=frozen)
        return add_init(cls, frozen)

    # See if we're being called as @dataclass or @dataclass().
    if _cls is None:
        # We're called with parens.
        return wrap

    # We're called as @dataclass without parens.
    return wrap(_cls)
```

(also posted as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/noamkush/30574dd552faeed2e460ea72d570b533), tested with Python 3.6 backport)

This will require to define the child class as

```py
@dataclass_keyword_only
class Child(Parent):
    school: str
    ugly: bool = True
```

And would generate `__init__(self, *, name:str, age:int, ugly:bool=True, school:str)` (which is valid python). The only caveat here is not allowing to initialize objects with positional arguments, but otherwise it's a completely regular `dataclass` with no ugly hacks.

Comment: Thx, super nice solution, the only problem that I see is that this is not compatible with mypy, I'm trying to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I came back to this question after discovering that dataclasses [may](https://bugs.python.org/issue36077) be getting a decorator parameter that allows fields to be reordered. This is certainly a promising development, though progress on this feature seems to have stalled somewhat.

Right now, you can get this behaviour, plus some other niceties, by using [**dataclassy**](https://github.com/biqqles/dataclassy), my reimplementation of dataclasses that overcomes frustrations like this. Using `from dataclassy` in place of `from dataclasses` in the original example means it runs without errors.

Using [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) to print the signature of `Child` makes what is going on clear; the result is `(name: str, age: int, school: str, ugly: bool = True)`. Fields are always reordered so that fields with default values come after fields without them in the parameters to the initializer. Both lists (fields without defaults, and those with them) are still ordered in definition order.

Coming face to face with this issue was one of the factors that prompted me to write a replacement for dataclasses. The workarounds detailed here, while helpful, require code to be contorted to such an extent that they completely negate the readability advantage dataclasses' naive approach (whereby field ordering is trivially predictable) offers.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution:

```
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    school: Optional[str] = None
    ugly: bool = True

    def __post_init__(self):
        assert self.school is not None
```

Then go back and refactor once (hopefully) the language is extended.

Answer (score 2):

When you use Python inheritance to create dataclasses, you cannot guarantee that *all* fields with default values will appear after *all* fields without default values.

An easy solution is to avoid using multiple inheritance to construct a "merged" dataclass. Instead, we can build a merged dataclass just by filtering and sorting on the fields of your parent dataclasses.

Try out this `merge_dataclasses()` function:

```py
import dataclasses
import functools
from typing import Iterable, Type


def merge_dataclasses(
    cls_name: str,
    *,
    merge_from: Iterable[Type],
    **kwargs,
):
    """
    Construct a dataclass by merging the fields
    from an arbitrary number of dataclasses.

    Args:
        cls_name: The name of the constructed dataclass.

        merge_from: An iterable of dataclasses
            whose fields should be merged.

        **kwargs: Keyword arguments are passed to
            :py:func:`dataclasses.make_dataclass`.

    Returns:
        Returns a new dataclass
    """
    # Merge the fields from the dataclasses,
    # with field names from later dataclasses overwriting
    # any conflicting predecessor field names.
    each_base_fields = [d.__dataclass_fields__ for d in merge_from]
    merged_fields = functools.reduce(
        lambda x, y: {**x, **y}, each_base_fields
    )

    # We have to reorder all of the fields from all of the dataclasses
    # so that *all* of the fields without defaults appear
    # in the merged dataclass *before* all of the fields with defaults.
    fields_without_defaults = [
        (f.name, f.type, f)
        for f in merged_fields.values()
        if isinstance(f.default, dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE)
    ]
    fields_with_defaults = [
        (f.name, f.type, f)
        for f in merged_fields.values()
        if not isinstance(f.default, dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE)
    ]
    fields = [*fields_without_defaults, *fields_with_defaults]

    return dataclasses.make_dataclass(
        cls_name=cls_name,
        fields=fields,
        **kwargs,
    )
```

And then you can merge dataclasses as follows. Note that we can merge `A` and `B` and the default fields `b` and `d` are moved to the end of the merged dataclass.

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: int = 0


@dataclasses.dataclass
class B:
    c: int
    d: int = 0


C = merge_dataclasses(
    "C",
    merge_from=[A, B],
)

# Note that 
print(C(a=1, d=1).__dict__)
# {'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
```

Of course, the pitfall of this solution is that `C` doesn't actually *inherit* from `A` and `B`, which means that you cannot use `isinstance()` or other type assertions to verify C's parentage.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.10 dataclasses have a kw_only=True attribute that eliminate this problem. The following works without error:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Parent:
    name: str
    age: int
    ugly: bool = False

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

    def print_age(self):
        print(self.age)

    def print_id(self):
        print(f'The Name is {self.name} and {self.name} is {self.age} year old')

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Child(Parent):
    school: str
    ugly: bool = True

jack = Parent(name='jack snr', age=32, ugly=True)
jack_son = Child(name='jack jnr', age=12, school='havard', ugly=True)

jack.print_id()
jack_son.print_id()
```

Note that you have to specify the arg names for all the fields when instantiating the class.

Comment: I copied your solution exactly as it is here, using Python 3.11, and while the script _might_ run successfully, the IDE is still complaining about 'Non-default argument(s) follows default argument(s)’. 

This is pointed on another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the Martijn Pieters solution that uses [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/): it is possible to create the inheritance without the default attributes replication, with:

```
import attr

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class Parent:
    name: str
    age: int
    ugly: bool = attr.ib(default=False, kw_only=True)


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class Child(Parent):
    school: str
    ugly: bool = True
```

More about the `kw_only` parameter can be found [here](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html?highlight=kw_only#keyword-only-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

How about defining the `ugly` field like this, instead of the default way?

```
ugly: bool = field(metadata=dict(required=False, missing=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

An experimental but interesting solution would be to use metaclasses. The solution below enables the usage of Python dataclasses with simple inheritance without using the `dataclass` decorator at all. Moreover, it makes it possible to inherit the fields of the parent base classes without complaining about the order of positional arguments(non-default fields).

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import typing as ty
import dataclasses
from itertools import takewhile

class DataClassTerm:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls)

class DataClassMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        fields = {}

        # Get list of base classes including the class to be produced(initialized without its original base classes as those have already become dataclasses)
        bases_and_self = [dataclasses.dataclass(super().__new__(cls, clsname, (DataClassTerm,), clsdict))] + list(bases)

        # Whatever is a subclass of DataClassTerm will become a DataClassTerm. 
        # Following block will iterate and create individual dataclasses and collect their fields
        for base in bases_and_self[::-1]: # Ensure that last fields in last base is prioritized
            if issubclass(base, DataClassTerm):
                to_dc_bases = list(takewhile(lambda c: c is not DataClassTerm, base.__mro__))
                for dc_base in to_dc_bases[::-1]: # Ensure that last fields in last base in MRO is prioritized(same as in dataclasses)
                    if dataclasses.is_dataclass(dc_base):
                        valid_dc = dc_base
                    else:
                        valid_dc = dataclasses.dataclass(dc_base)
                    for field in dataclasses.fields(valid_dc):
                        fields[field.name] = (field.name, field.type, field)
        
        # Following block will reorder the fields so that fields without default values are first in order
        reordered_fields = OrderedDict()
        for n, t, f  in fields.values():
            if f.default is dataclasses.MISSING and f.default_factory is dataclasses.MISSING:
                reordered_fields[n] = (n, t, f)
        for n, t, f  in fields.values():
            if n not in reordered_fields.keys():
                reordered_fields[n] = (n, t, f)
        
        # Create a new dataclass using `dataclasses.make_dataclass`, which ultimately calls type.__new__, which is the same as super().__new__ in our case
        fields = list(reordered_fields.values())
        full_dc = dataclasses.make_dataclass(cls_name=clsname, fields=fields, init=True, bases=(DataClassTerm,))
        
        # Discard the created dataclass class and create new one using super but preserve the dataclass specific namespace.
        return super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, {**full_dc.__dict__,**clsdict})
    
class DataClassCustom(DataClassTerm, metaclass=DataClassMeta):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args)>0:
            raise RuntimeError("Do not use positional arguments for initialization.")
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now let's create a sample dataclass with a parent dataclass and a sample mixing class:

```
class DataClassCustomA(DataClassCustom):
    field_A_1: int = dataclasses.field()
    field_A_2: ty.AnyStr = dataclasses.field(default=None)

class SomeOtherClass:
    def methodA(self):
        print('print from SomeOtherClass().methodA')

class DataClassCustomB(DataClassCustomA,SomeOtherClass):
    field_B_1: int = dataclasses.field()
    field_B_2: ty.Dict = dataclasses.field(default_factory=dict)
```

The result is

```
result_b = DataClassCustomB(field_A_1=1, field_B_1=2)

result_b
# DataClassCustomB(field_A_1=1, field_B_1=2, field_A_2=None, field_B_2={})

result_b.methodA()
# print from SomeOtherClass().methodA
```

An attempt to do the same with `@dataclass` decorator on each parent class would have raised an exception in the following child class, like `TypeError(f'non-default argument <field-name) follows default argument')`. The above solution prevents this from happening because the fields are first reordered. However, since the order of fields is modified the prevention of `*args` usage in `DataClassCustom.__new__` is mandatory as the original order is no longer valid.

Although in Python >=3.10 the `kw_only` feature was introduced that essentially makes inheritance in dataclasses much more reliable, the above example still can be used as a way to make dataclasses inheritable that do not require the usage of `@dataclass` decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Decorator `@dataclass` has option `init=False`, [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#module-level-decorators-classes-and-functions):

> init: If true (the default), a `__init__`() method will be generated. If
> the class already defines **init**(), this parameter is ignored.

For this example we could use option to set custom, old-school (and boring), `__init__` constructor, but then we could set order and defaults as we like (works for python 3.7+):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Parent:
    name: str
    age: int
    ugly: bool = False

@dataclass(init=False)
class Child(Parent):
    school: str
    ugly: bool = True
    new_id: int

    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int, school: str, 
                 new_id:int, ugly: bool = True):
        self.name, self.age, self.school, self.new_id, \
             self.ugly = name, age, school, new_id, ugly

jack = Parent('jack snr', 32, ugly=True)
jack_son = Child('jack jnr', 12, school = 'havard', 
                 ugly=True, new_id=12)

print(jack)
# -> Parent(name='jack snr', age=32, ugly=True)
print(jack_son)
# -> Child(name='jack jnr', age=12, ugly=True, school='havard', 
#          new_id=12)
```

Since `__init__` method is not generated, one must be aware of that:

- dataclass field defaults (i.e. `default`, `default_factory`) are ignored - you must (re)define default values in `__init__()` method declaration
- `__init__` method + `init=False` can be defined/set only in child class only, parent class can stay as is
- `InitVar`, `ClassVar` and similar dataclass type hints are ignored
- rule to have order of dataclass fields "first fields without defaults -> then fields with defaults" is not applied, you may do whatever you like - check `new_id` in example (although default values ignored anyway, see first note)

To conclude, it is very handy and safe when dataclass generates `__init__` method, so use this *custom `__init__`* technique when there is really no better option. Personally, I prefer solution with `kw_only=True` solution better.