# Is there a workaround about dataclass attribute mypy error?

Tags: python, mypy

Mypy produce an error with this dataclass inheritance:

```py
import dataclasses
import datetime

import typing


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Crud:
    creation_datetime: typing.Optional[datetime.datetime] = dataclasses.field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        self.creation_datetime = getattr(self, "creation_datetime", datetime.datetime.utcnow())


@dataclasses.dataclass
class MyFoo(Crud):
    name: str
```

```
t.py:17: error: Attributes without a default cannot follow attributes with one
```

Does exist a way to supress this error or design the code differently to avoid mypy error ?

Comment: A technical explanation and a workaround are provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575931/class-inheritance-in-python-3-7-dataclasses. It does not really answer to *why* though.

Answer (score -5):

For information, this error can be avoided with   `# type: ignore`

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class MyFoo(Crud):
    name: str  # type: ignore
```