# declaring a default value in a sub class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

Is it possible to declare a default value for an attribute in a subclass in python?

Eg something like this:

```
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class BaseClass:
    b: str
    a: str


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    c: str
    d: str
    a: str = "my value"
```

I tried this and I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: non-default argument 'c' follows default argument

I also tried putting `a` before `c` and `d` in the subclass without success (same error).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It's telling you to put `a` before `c` and `d`. What's confusing you about the error message?

Comment: I tried that, it throws the same error

Comment: Could you please add a plain python tag as the python-3.x tag guidance suggests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class inheritance in Python 3.7 dataclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575931/class-inheritance-in-python-3-7-dataclasses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derived class will have the following order of fields in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(b, a, c, d):
```

This is because `a` appears in the base class, so the base constructor is

```
def __init__(b, a):
```

To give `a` a default value, can give `c` and `d` default values (e.g. `None`):

```
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    c: str = None
    d: str = None
    a: str = "my value"
```

Comment: question is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575931/class-inheritance-in-python-3-7-dataclasses

Comment: Good find. You should close it as such then

Comment: Type of c, d should be `Optional[str]` then

Comment: @M.Winkens. Yes