# Python dataclasses inheritance and default values

Tags: python

Given the following hierarchy of python dataclasses:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    aa: str


@dataclass
class B(A):
    b: str


@dataclass
class C(A):
    c: str


@dataclass
class D(B, C):
    d: str
```

Is there any general method that allows you to insert an attribute with a default value in this inheritance hierarchy? For instance, the following produces a `Non-default argument(s) follows default argument(s) defined in 'B'` error for class `D`.

```
@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    aa: str


@dataclass
class B(A):
    b: str = 'b'  # <-- default value


@dataclass
class C(A):
    c: str


@dataclass
class D(B, C):
    d: str
```

I suppose one solution could be to give all attributes in the hierarchy a default value of `None`, and add a `__post_init__()` validation which raises some exception if any attributes are `None`, but this doesn't seem right and you would need it in every dataclass in the hierarchy.

[Class inheritance in Python 3.7 dataclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575931/class-inheritance-in-python-3-7-dataclasses) proposes a solution where you create two separate branches of the inheritance hierarchy; one for default values and one without. The drawback here is that the hierarchy quickly becomes mangled with a lot of classes, but if there are no better options, I suppose this is as good as it gets.

## Edit

I've come up with a `meta_dataclass` which does some hackery to at least solve my problem. I'm sure it breaks all kinds of rules, but perhaps someone can improve upon it.

It allows a hierarchy of `meta_dataclasses` where any attribute in the hierarchy can have a default value. It is motivated by the solution presented in [Class inheritance in Python 3.7 dataclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575931/class-inheritance-in-python-3-7-dataclasses). It effectively creates two inheritance branches, one with default values and one without, but the creation of the extra classes required to achieve this is encapsulated in the `mete_dataclass` decorator. A current drawback is that a `meta_dataclass` can only inherit from other `meta_dataclasses`.

**Full code**:

```
from dataclasses import make_dataclass, MISSING, field


class Dataclass:
    pass


class Declarations:
    pass


class Definitions:
    pass


def meta_dataclass(cls=None, /, *, init=True, repr=True, eq=True, order=False, unsafe_hash=False, frozen=False):
    def wrap(cls):
        declaration_bases = []
        definition_bases = []

        for base in cls.__bases__:
            if issubclass(base, Dataclass):
                declaration_bases += [c for c in base.__bases__ if issubclass(c, Declarations)]
                definition_bases += [c for c in base.__bases__ if issubclass(c, Definitions)]
            elif len(cls.__bases__) == 1 and base != object:
                raise ValueError(f'meta_dataclasses can only inherit from other meta_dataclasses. '
                                 f'{cls} inherits from {base}')

        declaration_bases.append(Declarations)
        definition_bases.append(Definitions)

        fields = []
        if hasattr(cls, '__annotations__'):
            for field_name, field_type in cls.__annotations__.items():
                f = field(default=cls.__dict__[field_name]) if field_name in cls.__dict__ else field()
                fields.append((field_name, field_type, f))

        declarations = make_dataclass(cls_name=f'{cls.__name__}_Declarations',
                                      bases=tuple(declaration_bases),
                                      fields=[f for f in fields if isinstance(f[2].default, type(MISSING))],
                                      init=init, repr=repr, eq=eq, order=order, unsafe_hash=unsafe_hash, frozen=frozen)

        definitions = make_dataclass(cls_name=f'{cls.__name__}_Definitions',
                                     bases=tuple(definition_bases),
                                     fields=[f for f in fields if not isinstance(f[2].default, type(MISSING))],
                                     init=init, repr=repr, eq=eq, order=order, unsafe_hash=unsafe_hash, frozen=frozen)

        cls_wrapper = make_dataclass(cls_name=cls.__name__, fields=[], bases=(Dataclass, definitions, declarations),
                                     namespace=cls.__dict__, init=init, repr=repr, eq=eq, order=order,
                                     unsafe_hash=unsafe_hash, frozen=frozen)

        return cls_wrapper

    if cls is None:
        return wrap
    else:
        return wrap(cls)
```

**Example**:

```
@meta_dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    aa: str

@meta_dataclass
class B(A):
    b: str = 'b'

@meta_dataclass
class C(A):
    c: str

@meta_dataclass
class D(B, C):
    d: str


>>> help(D)
Help on class D in module types:

class D(__main__.Dataclass, D_Definitions, D_Declarations)
 |  D(a: str, aa: str, c: str, d: str, b: str = 'b') -> None
 |  
 |  D(a: str, aa: str, c: str, d: str, b: str = 'b')
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      D
 |      __main__.Dataclass
 |      D_Definitions
 |      B_Definitions
 |      C_Definitions
 |      A_Definitions
 |      __main__.Definitions
 |      D_Declarations
 |      B_Declarations
 |      C_Declarations
 |      A_Declarations
 |      __main__.Declarations
 |      builtins.object
```

**Illustration**:

The below image illustrates what the `@meta_dataclass` decorator does to a single class.

[image: Illustration of what @meta_dataclass does]

Answer (score 19):

This is a well-known issue for data classes, there are several workarounds but this is solved very elegantly in Python 3.10, here is the PR that solved the [issue 43532](https://bugs.python.org/issue43532).

It would work the following way:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Base:
  type: str
  counter: int = 0

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Foo(Base):
  id: int
```

This is deeply explained at: https://medium.com/@aniscampos/python-dataclass-inheritance-finally-686eaf60fbb5

---

For the original question, `C` and `D` are the minimum required classes to have the `kw_only` flag set to `True`:

```py
@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    aa: str


@dataclass
class B(A):
    b: str = 'b'  # <-- default value


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class C(A):
    c: str


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class D(B, C):
    d: str
```

Although all of them could have the flag set to True for this matter.