# dataclass inheritance: Fields without default values cannot appear after fields with default values

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

### Context

I created two data classes to handle table metadata. `TableMetadata` apply to any kind of tables, while `RestTableMetadata` contains information relevant for data extracted from REST apis

```py
@dataclass
class TableMetadata:
    """
    - entity: business entity represented by the table
    - origin: path / query / url from which data withdrawn
    - id: field to be used as ID (unique)
    - historicity: full, delta
    - upload: should the table be uploaded
    """

    entity: str
    origin: str
    view: str
    id: str = None
    historicity: str = "full"
    upload: bool = True
    columns: list = field(default_factory=list)


@dataclass
class RestTableMetadata(TableMetadata):
    """
    - method: HTTP method to be used
    - payloadpath: portion of the response payload to use to build the dataframe
    """

    method: str
    payloadpath: str = None
```

### Problem

Because of inheritance, `method` (without default values) comes after `columns`, resulting in the following **Pylance** error: `Fields without default values cannot appear after fields with default values`

I'm looking for a way to fix it without overriding `__init__` (if there is such a way). I also noticed a method called `__init_subclass__` (*This method is called when a class is subclassed.*) that might affect how `RestTableMetadata.__init__` and other subclasses is generated.

Comment: I think this answer has a lot of detail, such as use of `__post_init__` and `attrs` library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575931/class-inheritance-in-python-3-7-dataclasses. EDIT: Looks like Python 3.10 offers some new options as well. Details in the linked question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a working solution for python > 3.10

```py
@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class TableMetadata:
    """
    - entity: business entity represented by the table
    - origin: path / query / url from which data withdrawn
    - id: field to be used as ID (unique)
    - historicity: full, delta
    - upload: should the table be uploaded
    """

    entity: str
    origin: str
    view: str
    id: str = None
    historicity: str = "full"
    upload: bool = True
    columns: list = field(default_factory=list)


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class RestTableMetadata(TableMetadata):
    """
    - method: HTTP method to be used
    - payloadpath: portion of the response payload to use to build the dataframe
    """

    method: str
    payloadpath: str = None
```

Comment: What about version 3.9?

Comment: @FaCoffee : have a look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53085935/7648881](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53085935/7648881)

Comment: This answer worked better for me for 3.8/3.9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58525728/569183