# Reserved word as an attribute name in a dataclass when parsing a JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I stumbled upon a problem, when I was working on my ETL pipeline. I am using dataclasses `dataclass` to parse JSON objects. One of the keywords of the JSON object is a reserved keyword. Is there a way around this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import jsons

out = {"yield": 0.21}

@dataclass
class PriceObj:
    asOfDate: str
    price: float
    yield: float

jsons.load(out, PriceObj)
```

This will obviously fail because `yield` is reserved. Looking at the dataclasses `field` definition, there doesn't seem to be anything in there that can help.

Go, allows one to define the name of the JSON field, wonder if there is such a feature in the `dataclass`?

Comment: I have a solution, replace all the Python reserved words in the JSON object's keys before sending it to load lol

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911616/7194553 (spoiler: it's not trivial, you'll probably want to use a different pattern)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can decode / encode using a different name with the `dataclasses_json` lib, from their [docs](https://lidatong.github.io/dataclasses-json/):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from dataclasses_json import config, dataclass_json

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Person:
    given_name: str = field(metadata=config(field_name="overriddenGivenName"))

Person(given_name="Alice")  # Person('Alice')
Person.from_json('{"overriddenGivenName": "Alice"}')  # Person('Alice')
Person('Alice').to_json()  # {"overriddenGivenName": "Alice"}
```

Comment: `dataclasses_json` is an incredibly useful lib that allows you to do many more cool things. For example, it gives you hook access to the decoder / encoder methods per dataclass field!

Answer (score 0):

I found next solution for my purposes.

```
@dataclass
class ExampleClass:
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.__setattr__("class", self.class_)
        self.__delattr__("class_") 

    class_: str
```

It requires to set init value in `class_` attribute.
Also you can't directly use this attribute like `example_class_instance.class`, workaround is `example_class_instance.__getattribute__("class")`.
And the dataclass has broken repr, can be avoided by changing decorator to `dataclass(repr=False)`